# Windows takes way too long to boot

Tags: boot, windows-8.1

Recently I've been having problems with the boot time of Windows 8.1. Here's the information of the boot trace:

[image]

As you can see the PreSMSS phase takes way too long - over 96 seconds - and the ExplorerInit phase 17 seconds which I think isn't normal since my system used to take 30 seconds or less. Also the PostExplorerPeriod and TraceTail durations are set to -1. Is this some kind of bug?

Can somebody please help me?

PS: I can give all the needed information of the .xml, I just didn't post it right away so that the question's body isn't excessively long.

Comment: Have you Googled anything on slow boot time regarding PreSMSS?

Comment: @MatthewWilliams I have, extensively. I  found that boot delay in that phase is due to delay in initializing some device. I looked in the pnp node and indeed there's one device that takes a really long time but it's named: "PCI\VEN_8086+DEV_1E03+SUBSYS_C652144D+REV_04\3+11583659+0+FA". I googled it but no information regarding what device this might be was found =/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PCI Vendor 8086 is Intel, and the device (DEV) 1E03 is:

> DEV_1E03
>
> Intel(R) 7 Series Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller
>
> Intel(R) 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller - 1E03

Check your SATA cable, or maybe your disk is going bad.

You also may want to go to the [Intel Driver Update](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/detect) utility and make sure you have the latest storage or chipset drivers from them.

Comment: Well after my initial freaking out moment when I thought I would have to be without pc for a week I checked the drivers. Indeed they weren't up to date, although they worked fine until a day or so and I don't believe I've updated any other driver. Problem fixed. The PreSMSS phase now only takes 4 seconds. Thank you!